# Display all dates even no data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query,

```
select value, updateddate from valid_table where date(updateddate) between '2018-11-01' and '2018-11-07';

value date
40    2018-11-01
50    2018-11-03
70    2018-11-05
```

But I want to display all dates even if there is no data for particular date like below,

```
value date
40    2018-11-01
0     2018-11-02
50    2018-11-03
0     2018-11-04
70    2018-11-05
0     2018-11-06
0     2018-11-07
```

**Note : start and end date may come 2018-10-01 and 2018-12-01**

How to achieve this?

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: @fa06 version is 5.5

Comment: take a look of this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179375

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using left join

```
 select tdate, coalesce(value,0) as value from 
    (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) tdate from
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
     (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) t1
    left join valid_table on t1.tdate= updateddate 
    where tdate between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the dates between start and end date you can use below query. Hope this can help you. To get this result from table you can use joins.

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```